# ComboBoxEx and events

Tags: delphi, controls, delphi-2010, vcl

I added ComboBoxEx control to my form and populate it with data from database. I set AutoSuggest, AutoAppend and UpDownKeyDropsList to true.

First I tried OnSelect event - it doesn't fire If I'm typing to combobox and selecting an item from dropdown.

Then I tried OnDropDown event - it doesn't fire either if dropdown is dropped down.

Now how can I get selected item when item is selected?

Comment: How can I get the item from there? It check what I type.

Comment: I mean, how can I check from there if item is selected? Because I don't want to check if characters are typed.

Comment: Normally 'OnEndEdit' event should do, together with 'OnSelect' in case the user do not type anything and select directly from the drop-down. But I admit 'OnEndEdit' works a bit weird, it doesn't have the correct ItemIndex the first time the choice appears, you have to press 'Enter' again or set the focus to sth. else.

Comment: Is there any n00b friendly solutions?

Comment: @evilone - Not that I know of. The VCL completely ignores the paramters of `CBEN_ENDEDIT` notification which contains the necessary information (including the item that's going to be selected). The way I see it you'd need to derive a control/subclass the ComboBoxEx... I hope someone comes up with a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I don't understand the question I think the answer you are looking for is the onChange event and then use ComboBox.Items[ComboBox.ItemIndex] to get the selected item.

EDIT: You could also check to see if ComboBox.ItemIndex <> -1 in the onChange event. Using this you could get around doing your important code for the event each time a letter is typed.

Although I only did a quick test, there is still issue with once an item is selected any typing after that doesn't get caught by "itemIndex <> -1" since it has been set. Though this seems like a good start.